# Bulk copy files on google drive from a list of hyperlinks

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a list of 200 hyperlinks saved on a spreadsheet. Those links are for files (particularly Google Slides files) all saved in Google Drive. They are scattered in sub folders under the same root folder that has ~1500 files

Link 1
Link 2
Link 3
...
Link 200

I want to make a copy of those 200 files only. There is no common search term or filter to pull them up on Google Drive search. So I need to work off that list

Thoughts on doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Although, unfortunately, I cannot understand about the structure of each URL of `200 hyperlinks` from your question, I think that if the file ID is included in the URL, your goal can be achieve using a script. But, about `I want to make a copy of those 200 files only.`, where is the destination of the copied files? By this, the language for achieving your goal might be decided.

Comment: All hyperlinks are stored in a spreadsheet in the following format

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/FILE_ID

The destination is another folder in my drive. (source is a shared folder in drive that I have edit access to)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying and `200 hyperlinks`, I thought that the batch request might be suitable for your situation. So I posted the sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your current situation and your goal as follows.

- You have the Spreadsheet including 200 hyperlinks of Google Slides like `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/FILE_ID`.
- You want to copy the Google Slides to the specific folder in your Google Drive.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

From the number of hyperlinks, I thought that in this case, the batch request might be useful for your situation. When the batch request is used, the process cost will become low because the batch request is run with the asynchronous process. So, in this answer, I would like to propose to copy the files of 200 hyperlinks using the batch request. The sample script is as follows.

### Usage:

#### 1. Install a Google Apps Script library.

In this script, in order to achieve the batch request, a Google Apps Script library is used. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest) I thought that the request of the batch request might be a bit complecate. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch#example) So I created this library for using the batch request with Google Apps Script. The library's project key is as follows.

```
1HLv6tWz0oXFOJHerBTP8HsNmhpRqssijJatC92bv9Ym6HSN69_UuzcDk
```

The method for installing the library can be seen at the official document. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)

#### 2. Sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of your Google Spreadsheet including 200 hyperlinks like `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/FILE_ID`. This script used Drive API. So, before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, run the function "myFunction".

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const destinationFolderId = "###"; // Please set the destination folder ID.
  
  // 1. Retrieve file IDs from Spreadsheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const fileIds = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((ar, [a]) => {
    if ((/^https:\/\/docs.google.com\/presentation\/d/).test(a)) ar.push(a.split("/")[5]);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  
  console.log(fileIds) // You can check the retrieved file ID.
  
  // 2. Retrieve the filenames form the file IDs using the "Files: get" method with the batch request.
  const requests1 = fileIds.map(id => ({
    method: "GET",
    endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${id}?supportsAllDrives=true`,
  }));
  const res1 = BatchRequest.EDo({batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests: requests1});

  console.log(res1) // You can check the retrieved file metadata.

  // 3. Copy the files using the file IDs and filenames using the "Files: copy" method with the batch request.
  const requests2 = res1 .map(({id, name}) => ({
    method: "POST",
    endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${id}/copy?supportsAllDrives=true`,
    requestBody: {parents: [destinationFolderId || "root"], name},
  }));
  const res2 = BatchRequest.EDo({batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests: requests2});
  console.log(res2);
}
```

### Note:

- **In this sample script, it supposes that the 200 hyperlinks are put in the column "A" of "Sheet1". So, please modify this for your actual situation. Please be careful this.**

### References:

- [Batch request of official document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch)
- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)
- [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy)
- [BatchRequest of Google Apps Script library](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest)

Comment: The variables I changed are
- SheetName: name of the tab in the spreadsheet
- Destination FolderID: I created a folder in my drive and copied the text after /folders/ which includes ?resourcekey=0
- Range: A1:A. The file IDs are there
I enabled Drive API service and added the batchrequest library

I run & was asked to confirm permissions (done) and got: 
9:12:38 PM Notice Execution started
9:12:39 PM Info []
9:12:39 PM Notice Execution completed
Nothing was copied to the destination. I see we didn't identify the source folder, BTW I don't own it but I have edit access to

Comment: @Rasha Nasher Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `The variables I changed are - SheetName: name of the tab in the spreadsheet - Destination FolderID: I created a folder in my drive and copied the text after /folders/ which includes ?resourcekey=0 - Range: A1:A.`. I supposes that your URL in "A1:A" is like `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/FILE_ID`. If this is not correct, can I ask you about the sample URL in "A1:A"? By the way, the folder ID is `###` of `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/###`. How about this?

Comment: @Rasha Nasher And also, in your situation, those files are put in the shared drive? For this, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize again. At that time, can you provide the values of `console.log(fileIds)` and `console.log(res1)`? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear. I mean I copied the script and I just replaced the SheetName (the name of the tab) and the ID for Destination folder.
Yes the File IDs are in A1:A
Yes the files are in the shared drive and I want to copy them to my personal drive

Comment: SOLVED!!
@Tanaike.. Turns out your script requires the full URL, I was using the file ID in my list which I did as I mixed both your and Ale's responses :$
It only copied 24 files though. I broke it down to chunks of 20 to find out the erroneous ones. But for my purposes This works for now. Thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: @Rasha Nasher Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the links look something similar to this and they're stored in the `A` column:

```
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/SLIDE_ID/edit
```

You can easily extract the `slideId` from the hyperlink which corresponds to the `fileId` by making use of this formula (by dragging it down the whole `A` column):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"[-\w]{25,}")
```

Finally, in order to copy each file, you can make use of Apps Script’s `DriveApp`, something similar to this:

```
DriveApp.getFileById(“fileId”).makeCopy(“destination”);
```

However, since the `fileId` corresponds to a range in the sheet, you can pass directly the range - so instead of using “fileId”, you could use this:

```
let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(“spreadsheetId”).getSheetByName(“sheetName”);
let fileId = sheet.getRange(1,2).getValue();
```

The snippet above is retrieving the sheet where the links are stored and then by making use of the `getRange` and `getValue` methods it retrieves the value from the `B1` cell (assuming that the ids of the files will be in the `B` column after `REGEXEXTRACT`).

#### Note

Please bear in mind that you can extract the `fileId` as well directly in your script, depending on the workaround and programming language .

#### Reference

- [Files Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopydestination);
- [Spreadsheet Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet);
- [Range Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range);
- [REGEXEXTRACT function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en&ref_topic=3105625).

Comment: Thank you for your response! :) So I'll need to do this step by step... please bare with me! 

1st: The links are stored in a spreadsheet and they all have the Text (Link). So REGEXTRACT won't work on them. I manually copied the hyperlink into another cell just to try and was able to REGEXTRACT (need to get all the hyperlinks out in bulk but that's for later)  

Now that I have the ID (worked as expected) I'm just really getting started with script. Where would I do the post command?

Thank you! very basic questions I know, but just getting started!

Comment: update: I managed to extract all the File IDs from all the Links with REGEXTRACT. they're in spreadsheet format now. Don't know how to proceed with (POST)

Comment: So I just copied those 3 lines and got this:

Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp. CopyAll @ Code.gs:6

I thought I would remove the quotes from “fileId”  `DriveApp.getFileById(fileId)`

this time it run for 20 seconds but nothing appeared in the destination or anywhere.

For the folder and spreadsheet ID I assume I don't need the resourcekey part

Comment: Are you receiving any errors in the logs? @RashaNasher